# C# Populating multidimensional string array from Excel

Tags: c#, arrays, excel, multidimensional-array

Been a while since i have programmed, so forgive the rustiness.

I'm trying to populate a multidimensional string array, from an Excel sheet.

The array looks like this

```
string[,] calendarArray = new string[,]
   {
    {RowValue1,ColumnValue1},
    {RowValue2,ColumnValue1},
    etc
   };
```

I want to pull in RowValue and ColumnValue from from the Excel sheet. Pulling the data from Excel isn't the hurdle, can someone please let me know the most efficient way of getting the data into the string array?

Answer (score 0):

You can read `Range.Value` directly as an array. This gets an `Object[,]`, so not exactly the `String[,]` you requested, but see if this works for you:

```
dynamic obj = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
dynamic wb = obj.Workbooks(1);
Object[,] x = wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:C2").Value;
Console.WriteLine($"{x.GetLength(0)} x {x.GetLength(1)} items");
Console.WriteLine($"A2 = {x[2,1]}");
```

Comment: Thanks @KekuSemau , I will try it out tomorrow and let you know.